# Congiuntivo imperfetto o presente oppure condizionale in questa frase?

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood, conditional-mood, moods

Nel libro *Grammatica italiana per stranieri* di Maria Cristina Peccianti ho letto queste spiegazioni sull'uso dei modi verbali nelle proposizioni interrogative indirette:

> - Si usa il modo **congiuntivo** soprattutto nella lingua scritta e nella lingua parlata più formale: *Non riesco a decidere **quale sia la cosa migliore per me***.
> - Si usa il modo **condizionale** quando l'interrogativa indiretta esprime una domanda o un dubbio legati ad un'ipotesi: *Vorrei proprio capire **come ti saresti comportato al posto mio***.

Il mio problema è che non riesco a capire del tutto bene qual è la scelta corretta, congiuntivo o condizionale, in una frase che ho cercato di scrivere. Ecco: quale tra queste due sarebbe la forma corretta?

> Il governo spagnolo non permette il referendum con il quale si dovrebbe decidere se la Catalogna **dovesse diventare** uno stato indipendente.

oppure

> Il governo spagnolo non permette il referendum con il quale si dovrebbe decidere se la Catalogna **dovrebbe diventare** uno stato indipendente.

Dovrei scegliere il condizionale argomentando che si tratta di una domanda legata all'ipotesi della Catalogna come un possibile futuro stato independente?

**Aggiornamento:** 
Grazie alla risposta di @Noya, mi sono accorta che c'è una terza possibilità, quella di usare il congiuntivo presente:

> Il governo spagnolo non permette il referendum con il quale si dovrebbe decidere se la Catalogna **debba diventare** uno stato indipendente.

Il mio dubbio è quale di queste tre opzioni
sarebbe la scelta corretta e perché.

Comment: Non vedo interrogative indirette.

Comment: @egreg: Non pensi che l'esempio di interrogativa indiretta della Peccianti, *Non riesco a decidere quale sia la cosa migliore per me* sia simile alla mia frase? Potrei anche scrivere "Non riesco a decidere se la Catalogna debba diventare uno stato indipendente" ed è la stessa struttura, no?

Answer (score 3):

Partiamo da una frase più semplice, senza la doppia subordinata:

> La Catalogna deve diventare uno stato indipendente?
>
> Si deve decidere se la Catalogna **debba** diventare uno stato indipendente.

Tempo presente, contemporaneità. Questo rientra anche nelle tabelle che ti ha linkato Noya.

Quand'è che si usa il condizionale, invece? Quando nella domanda c'è un periodo ipotetico:

> Come ti saresti comportato *se fossi stato* al posto mio?
>
> Vorrei proprio capire come ti **saresti comportato** *se fossi stato* al posto mio.

Questo perché c'è un limite alla complicazione dei modi verbali che si possono mettere in una frase italiana: dovremmo mettere quella domanda indiretta nel "congiuntivo condizionale presente", ma questo modo non esiste. Quindi:

```
indicativo -> congiuntivo
condizionale -> condizionale
```

Ora, il punto delicato è che in questo periodo ipotetico possiamo lasciare implicita la condizione:

> Come ti saresti comportato al posto mio?
>
> Vorrei proprio capire come ti **saresti comportato** al posto mio.

O anche toglierla completamente:

> Come ti saresti comportato? (se fossi stato al posto mio)
>
> Vorrei proprio capire come ti **saresti comportato**.

Quindi quel condizionale in realtà sta lì perché c'è sotto, implicitamente, un periodo ipotetico. Altrimenti, se non c'è questo periodo ipotetico implicito, si usa normalmente il congiuntivo. La tua grammatica cerca di sintetizzare questa idea con "una domanda legata a un'ipotesi", ma mi sembra più chiaro spiegato così come l'ho fatto io.

Nel tuo caso, tu stai pensando a

> La Catalogna dovrebbe diventare uno stato indipendente, se vincesse il referendum?
>
> Si deve decidere se la Catalogna **dovrebbe** diventare uno stato indipendente (se vincesse il referendum).

che mi suona innaturale ma potrei anche considerare corretto, se stiamo parlando di uno scenario ben più contorto. La situazione sarebbe questa: c'è un referendum, vince l'indipendenza, il governo spagnolo decide di non concederla contro il volere del popolo. E ti sto chiedendo: fa bene o fa male? Come quando si pensava che il parlamento inglese non volesse confermare la Brexit.

Ma in questo caso la domanda che vogliamo fare agli elettori è più semplice: "la Catalogna deve diventare uno stato indipendente?", non "se la Catalogna vincesse il referendum, dovrebbe diventare uno stato indipendente?". Non c'è questo periodo ipotetico nascosto.

In altre parole: un'interrogativa indiretta sottintende sempre una domanda / dubbio / ipotesi; si usa il condizionale quando stiamo facendo una domanda su una situazione **che già di per sé è ipotetica** per la presenza di un'altra condizione aggiuntiva.

Comment: Mi hai convinta: si deve usare il congiuntivo nella mia frase. Ma adesso ho anche il dubbio: congiuntivo presente oppure congiuntivo imperfetto? (forse dovrei aggiungerlo alla domanda)

Comment: @Charo Per questo bastano tabelle come quelle che ti ha fornito Noya: tempo presente + contemporaneità = congiuntivo presente. Se si tratta di una domanda al presente è facile: il tempo della domanda non cambia, devi solo passare da indicativo a congiuntivo (a parte per il futuro, in cui si tiene l'indicativo perché il congiuntivo futuro non c'è: un altro caso di "c'è un limite alla complicazione dei verbi in italiano").

Comment: Il problema è che io ho usato il **condizionale** nella principale e non il presente indicativo: "si dovrebbe decidere...".

Comment: E i miei libri (e anche le tabelle di @Noya) dicono: "proposizione principale al condizionale" + contemporaneità = "proposizione secondaria al congiuntivo imperfetto".

Comment: Le tabelle di Noya però dicono che quelle regole diverse valgono "quando nella principale si ha un verbo che esprime volontà o desiderio (volere, desiderare, preferire, ecc.) coniugato al condizionale presente o passato."

Comment: Occhio anche a quando dici "il condizionale nella principale e non il presente": quel verbo è al condizionale presente. Modo e tempo sono due caratteristiche separate del verbo.

Comment: Hai ragione: avrei dovuto dire "presente indicativo".

Comment: No, il punto è che la prima regola secondo me vale anche quando il verbo è al condizionale presente, purché non si tratti di un verbo di volontà/desiderio. Quindi si applica anche nel tuo esempio del referendum, e conferma che il congiuntivo presente è il tempo corretto per la subordinata.

Comment: Non so se [questo sito](http://grammatica-italiana.dossier.net/grammatica-italiana-17.htm) sia affidabile o meno, ma l'esempio che appare là è: *Io crederei che tu sapessi*. Il verbo "credere" però non esprime desiderio né volontà. Quindi, questo esempio non sarebbe corretto e invece si dovrebbe dire "io crederei che tu sappia"?

Comment: Se vuoi puoi aprire un'altra domanda per chiedere conferme più autorevoli, ma a me personalmente suona giusto *crederei che tu sappia*.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Scusate, non ho seguito tutto lo scambio, ma “crederei che tu sappia” mi stride come un gessetto sulla lavagna, ma è un problema mio, perché vedo che anche Serianni lo ammette. E, già che ci sono, in Serianni (XIV.35-82, pp. 382-397 dell'edizione Garzanti, su proposizioni completive, oggettive, soggettive etc.) ci sono le risposte a tutti i dubbi, compresi quelli che uno non sa di avere.

Comment: @DaG Infatti, sono io il primo a dirlo, non fidatevi dei miei "mi suona giusto". :)

Answer (score -1):

In questo caso si usa il congiuntivo. Però si usa il congiuntivo presente per cui *se la Catalogna debba diventare* perché sono in rapporto di contemporaneità (si tratta di un'ipotesi attuale)

Ho trovato questa pagina che spiega le regole di concordanza del congiuntivo:

http://aulalingue.scuola.zanichelli.it/benvenuti/2012/10/18/la-concordanza-dei-tempi-con-il-congiuntivo-1/

http://aulalingue.scuola.zanichelli.it/benvenuti/2012/10/31/la-concordanza-dei-tempi-con-il-congiuntivo-2/

Comment: Scusa, ma non capisco la tua risposta. Secondo i link che hai riportato (e secondo i miei libri di grammatica), se la frase principale è al condizionale, la frase subordinata dovrebbe essere al congiuntivo imperfetto oppure al congiuntivo trapassato (quando esprime anteriorità), non al congiuntivo presente. Non capisco neanche perché la mia frase non rientri nel caso di "una domanda legata ad un'ipotesi" spiegato da Maria Cristina Peccianti.

Comment: ho corretto la risposta. La frase non esprime anteriorità perché il fatto di divenire indipendente non é successo in passato

Comment: Questo lo so: il problema è che, secondo i link che hai messo nella risposta, **non si usa il congiuntivo presente** in una proposizione subordinata che dipende da una proposizione principale al condizionale!

Comment: purtroppo non so dirti la regola precisa però si usa la frase al congiuntivo presente. Per esempio: "dovrei chiedermi se tu SIA all'altezza del compito che ti ho assegnato" questo perchè il compito che ho assegnato lo devi ancora svolgere o lo stai svolgendo

Comment: Le persone che hanno votato questa risposta sarebbero in grado di spiegarmi perché in questo caso si debbe usare il **congiuntivo presente**? Perché io proprio non capisco niente di niente.

Comment: Io ho sempre pensato che, in accordo con gli standard di Stack Exchange, una risposta tipo "questo è così perché lo dico io, ma veramente non so spiegare perché, e per di più metto dei link che sembrano contradirmi (o perlomeno dicono una cosa diversa da quella che affermo io)" non è da considerarsi una buona risposta. Quindi, scusatemi, ma non capisco i voti positivi.

Comment: Questo non significa che la risposta non possa essere corretta, semplicemente penso che, per poter essere considerata una buona risposta d'accordo agli standard di qualità di Stack Exchange, dovrebbe essere argomentata.

Comment: @Noya, che vuol dire «non so dirti la regola precisa però si usa la frase al congiuntivo presente»? È un po' come dire «non so quale sia la capitale della Francia però è Marsiglia».

Comment: @DaG mi dica lei la regola, e mi dica se le due possibili frasi della domanda sono giuste. Nella prima secondo me c'è un errore di concordanza in quanto dovesse esprime un tempo passato rispetto all'azione del dover decidere, la seconda é sbagliata per via del doppio condizionale.

Comment: Il primo link che ho riportato http://aulalingue.scuola.zanichelli.it/benvenuti/2012/10/18/la-concordanza-dei-tempi-con-il-congiuntivo-1/ nella prima tabella mostra la concordanza in caso di contemporaneità o posteriorità. Tralasciamo il fatto che la congiunzione principale sia al condizionale si tratta comunque di tempo presente per cui la concordanza prevede o il congiuntivo al presente o eventualmente potrebbe essere riformulata con il futuro semplice se si vuole esprimere posteriorità.