# Dubbio sulla concordanza del congiuntivo in una frase subordinata quando la reggente è al condizionale

Tags: grammar, verbs, subjunctive-mood, conditional-mood, moods

Si tratta di una [domanda collegata a quest'altra](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/7956/congiuntivo-imperfetto-o-presente-oppure-condizionale-in-questa-frase). Ho un dubbio che riguarda la concordanza di un congiuntivo quando è in dipendenza da un condizionale in una frase subordinata. La regola che ho letto nei miei libri di grammatica è questa:

> Se nella frase principale c'è un condizionale presente o un condizionale passato, nella frase secondaria si possono avere:
>
> - un congiuntivo trapassato se c'è un rapporto di anteriorità;
> - un congiuntivo imperfetto se c'è un rapporto di contemporaneità o posteriorità.

Ho copiato il passaggio precedente dal libro *Nuovo Contatto C1. Corso di lingua e civiltà italiana per stranieri* (Loescher Editore, Torino, 2013), ma altri libri di grammatica che ho consultato hanno spiegazioni simili. Questa regola appare anche su [questo sito web](http://grammatica-italiana.dossier.net/grammatica-italiana-17.htm), in cui appaiono questi esempi:

> Io crederei / avrei creduto che sapessi
>
> Io crederei / avrei creduto che avessi saputo

Tuttavia, dalla lettura di quello che spiega il [sito della Zanichelli](http://aulalingue.scuola.zanichelli.it/benvenuti/2012/10/31/la-concordanza-dei-tempi-con-il-congiuntivo-2/) mi è sembrato capire che questa regola sia valida soltanto "quando nella principale c’è un verbo che esprime volontà o desiderio coniugato al condizionale", come "volere, desiderare, preferire, ecc". È veramente così? Il verbo "credere", però, non esprime desiderio né volontà. Significa questo che gli esempi sopra riportati non sono corretti? Si dovrebbe invece scrivere

> Io crederei che sappia

per esprimere un rapporto di contemporaneità? E, per la stessa ragione, si dovrebbe dire

> Si dovrebbe decidere se la Catalogna debba diventare uno stato indipendente

e non

> Si dovrebbe decidere se la Catalogna dovesse diventare uno stato indipendente

?

Con quali modi e tempi verbali si devono esprimere i rapporti di posteriorità e anteriorità di una frase subordinata dipendente da "io crederei" o "si dovrebbe decidere"? E i rapporti di contemporaneità, posteriorità e anteriorità di una frase subordinata dipendente da "io avrei creduto" o "si sarebbe dovuto decidere"?

Comment: Una piccola nota. All'ultima riga: "si sarebbe dovuto decidere", perché la forma impersonale ha l'ausiliare essere nei tempi composti.

Comment: Hai ragione, @Benedetta! Faccio la correzione!

Answer (score 1):

Innanzitutto mi scuso perché la mia risposta (forse) non risolve i tuoi dubbi, ma ci gira intorno: purtroppo la mia grammatica, in termini di enunciazione di regole, è molto arrugginita.
Mi complimento anche per il tuo italiano, decisamente migliore del mio!

Secondo me gli esempi con "crederei" sono sbagliati, da madrelingua mi suonano completamente innaturali. Usare "credere" al condizionale è ridondante, in quanto il verbo esprime di per sé un dubbio.

Riguardo l'altra frase, mi suona decisamente innaturale anche questa.
Non capisco perché usi "Si dovrebbe decidere": questa non è un'eventualità, una decisione verrà presa sicuramente. L'incertezza in questa frase dovrebbe andare solo nell'esito della decisione. Quindi direi

```
Si deciderà se la Catalogna debba diventare...
```

Qualora volessi davvero usare la formulazione col condizionale, nessuno userebbe la frase così come la hai formulata, ma la riarrangeremmo così da avere una roba tipo:

```
La Catalogna dovrebbe decidere se diventare uno stato indipendente.
```

dove hai scelto un soggetto opportuno piuttosto che una forma impersonale.

Comment: Ho simplificato la frase da quella che avevo scritto nell'[altra domanda](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/7956/congiuntivo-imperfetto-o-presente-oppure-condizionale-in-questa-frase).

Comment: Ho letto. Io direi "debba". Al solito, cambierei la frase in

    "ll governo spagnolo non permette il referendum con il quale si dovrebbe decidere riguardo l'indipendenza della Catalogna"

Comment: Gli esempi che ti sembrano strani, non sono strani quando vengono contestualizzati. Ad esempio, è perfettamente normale sentire frasi tipo "_alla sua età, crederei che ormai ... e invece ..._" oppure "_nel corso di questo summit si dovrebbe decidere se... ma voi delegati continuate a litigare su questioni che nulla hanno a che fare con l'argomento!_"

Answer (score 0):

Il condizionale usato con un verbo che esprime dubbio come il verbo "credere" sembra ridondante ma non lo è; intendiamoci, non è che la risposta precedente sia sbagliata, anzi! È vero le frasi suonano male ma questo è perché il tuo libro di grammatica ha "tagliato" le frasi... e così tu non puoi vedere la funzione che ha la frase ipotetica. Considera questi esempi:

Crederei che tu sapessi cucinare solo se me lo dimostrassi.

Avrei creduto che tu avessi saputo rispondere meglio alle mie domande.

Questo è il cossidetto italiano accademico, ma sappiamo tutti che la lingua parlata è spesso diversa dalla lingua scritta, e questo è il modo che permette alla lingua di evolversi nel tempo. In una conversazione informale la gente userebbe molto probabilmente il presente o l'imperfetto indicativo invece del condizionale:

Credo che tu sappia cucinare solo se me lo dimostri!

Credevo che tu avresti risposto meglio alle mie domande!

Questo non è l'italiano accademico è semplicemente la lingua italiana informale parlata. Un altro esempio? Nell'italiano parlato non si una quasi mai il futuro semplice indicativo, si parla sempre al presente.

Fra due anni mi sposo!

L'estate prossima andiamo in gita a Campobasso.

La frase non è redundante, ma lo sembra per due motivi: perché l'esempio è stato "tagliato" come ho spiegato prima e perché è italiano accademico che è leggermente (soprattutto nella coniugazione dei verbi) diverso dall'italiano colloquiale parlato.

Per rispondere alla tua domanda io non ho mai letto ne sentito da nessuna parte che che questa regola è valida solo "quando nella principale c’è un verbo che esprime volontà o desiderio coniugato al condizionale", come "volere, desiderare, preferire, ecc". Secondo me non c'è questa restrizione nell'uso del condizionale. Puoi usare qualunque verbo:

Mangerei la pizza se tu sapessi come cucinarla.

Avrei mangiato la pizza se tu l'avessi cucinata con più acciughe.

Questa restrizione di cui tu parli non si riferisce al tipo di subordinata introdda dal "SE", si riferisce al congiuntivo ma non nelle frasi ipotetiche di questo tipo. Come tu ben saprai, il congiuntivo nelle frasi introdotte dal "CHE"  si regge solo se esprime volontà o desiderio o dubbio. Questo succede perché il congiuntivo di per sé stesso non esprime la realtà, esprime un'ipotesi. Se vuoi esprimere un fatto certo devi usare l'indicativo. Questa è la differenza fra il congiuntivo e l'indicativo.

Spero che vinca la lotteria.

Credo che abbia mangiato troppo.

Però non puoi dire

So che vinca la lotteria.

Mi rendo conto che abbia mangiato troppo.

Perché? Perché questi verbi non esprimono un ipotesi ma esprimono la realtà perciò vogliono l'indicativo:

So che vincerà/ha vinto la lotteria.

Mi rendo conto che hai mangiato troppo.

Questo è per  spiegare che questi verbi che tu hai citato (che esprimono volontà, desiderio o dubbio) si riferiscono solo all'uso del verbo nelle frasi ipotetiche introdotte dal "CHE".

Perciò la risposta finale alla tua domanda è: la regola che tu riporti è corretta ma non c'è la restrizione di cui parli; infatti il modo condizionale può coniugare ogni verbo nella frase ipotetica introdotta dal "SE".

Answer (score 0):

Per quanto riguarda la seconda parte della tua domanda:

Il congiuntivo in italiano è usato in diversi modi. Ci sono le frasi introdotte dal SE, e in questi casi non hai restrizioni e puoi usare ogni verbo (guarda l'esempio del mangiare la pizza che ho fatto nella risposta precedente).

La regola di cui parli si applica solo quando la frase è introdotta dal "CHE" (non dal "SE"). Quando la frase è introdotta dal "CHE", il verbo che non è retto dal "che" deve esprimere desiderio, opportunità o volontà.

Per quanto riguarda i rapporti di contemporaneità, posteriorità o anteriorità: [image: rapporti di contemporaneità, posteriorità o anteriorità]

Questa immagine che ho trovato descrive bene questi rapporti. E adesso capisco di cosa parlavi prima. ;)