# "D'accordo con", "d'accordo a" oppure altro?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-choice

Quando ho scritto [questo mio commento](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/7956/congiuntivo-imperfetto-o-presente-oppure-condizionale-in-questa-frase/7957#comment17094_7957) a un altro post, ho scritto "d'accordo agli standard". Tuttavia, ho avuto il dubbio se dovessi aver scritto "d'accordo con gli standard" o se la locuzione "d'accordo" non fosse affatto corretta in questo contesto e dovesse quindi esprimermi in un altro modo. Ho cercato il vocabolo "accordo" in alcuni dizionari, ma non ho trovato niente al riguardo. Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire il mio dubbio? Quale espressione dovrei usare?

Comment: Infatti, dovrebbe essere “in accordo con gli standard”.

Comment: Adesso che conosco la risposta, procedo a correggere il mio commento all'altro post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'espressione corretta dovrebbe essere ***in accordo con gli standard*** sebbene possa essere usata anche ***secondo gli standard***.

Infatti la differenza sta nelle preposizioni, visto che è corretto usare *in accordo* **con gli** *standard* e non *agli standard*